# Connect to Azure Database using Azure Web App

Tags: php, azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to connect to my Azure sql database using following code:

```
<?php
//Constants to connect with the database
define('DB_USERNAME', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
define('DB_HOST', 'xyz-server.database.windows.net');
define('DB_NAME', 'xyz_db');
```

```
<?php

//Class DbConnect
class DbConnect
{
    //Variable to store database link
    private $con;

    //Class constructor
    function __construct()
    {

    }

    //This method will connect to the database
    function connect()
    {
        //Including the constants.php file to get the database constants
        include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Constants.php';

        //connecting to mysql database
        $this->con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

        //Checking if any error occured while connecting
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        //finally returning the connection link 
        return $this->con;
    }

}
```

I'm getting this error

```
Type: ErrorException
Code: 2
Message: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/9002): The connection string may not be right. Please visit portal for references.
File: /home/site/wwwroot/blingoo/include/DbConnect.php
Line: 22
```

I'm just beginning with Azure. Maybe I'm missing something. If you could simply point how to connect my database and web app(where I'm using php files to connect to the database), that will be great.

Comment: did you open the firewall on the SQL database accordingly?

Comment: this error doesn't seem to be a firewall problem

Comment: @silent firewall is on

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar i tried, now I'm getting this error: Message: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/9002): The server name you tried cannot be found. Please use the correct name and retry. Please check your server name xyz-server.

Comment: `on` is not a matter, You should allow the client's IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that your code is trying to connect to MySQL rather than MSSQL.

To connect to MSSQL use the following:

```
<?php
    $serverName = "your_server.database.windows.net"; // update me
    $connectionOptions = array(
        "Database" => "your_database", // update me
        "Uid" => "your_username", // update me
        "PWD" => "your_password" // update me
    );
    //Establishes the connection
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
    $tsql= "SELECT TOP 20 pc.Name as CategoryName, p.name as ProductName
         FROM [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] pc
         JOIN [SalesLT].[Product] p
         ON pc.productcategoryid = p.productcategoryid";
    $getResults= sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
    echo ("Reading data from table" . PHP_EOL);
    if ($getResults == FALSE)
        echo (sqlsrv_errors());
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     echo ($row['CategoryName'] . " " . $row['ProductName'] . PHP_EOL);
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($getResults);
?>
```

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-php

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to connect to ***Azure SQL*** you can use [PDO_DBLIB](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) driver, if you have this extension installed. See `php -m`.

```
$config = [
    'dsn' => 'dblib:host=xyz-server.database.windows.net;dbname=xyz_db',
    'user' => 'username',
    'pass' => 'password',
];

$connection = new PDO($config['dsn'], $config['user'], $config['pass']);

$sth = $connection->prepare('Your query comes here;');
$sth->execute();
$rows = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // Do the processing here
}
```